# django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: customer/base.html

Tags: python, django

1. My customers urls.py

```
'''
    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.base ,name= 'customer-base'),
        path('Hall/', views.Hall ,name= 'customer-Hall'),
        path('Food_item/', views.Food_item ,name= 'customer-food'),
        path('About_us/', views.About_us ,name= 'customer-about'), 
    ]
    '''
```

2. My Web_project urls.py

```
'''
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('customer.urls')),
]
'''
```

3. My views.py

'''

```
def base(request):
    return render(request, "customer/base.html", {"title":"base"})

def Hall(request):
    return render(request, "customer/Hall.html", {"title":"Hall"})

def Food_item(request):
    return render(request, "customer/Food_item.html", {"title":"Food"})

def About_us(request):
    return render(request, "customer/About_us.html", {"title":"About"})
```

'''

I have tried everything but did not work for me.

Comment: have you installed app in your settings.py file ?

Comment: 'INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'customer.apps.customerConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]'

Comment: what is your template location ?

Comment: web_project  > customer  > templates >  customer > home.html

Comment: `web_project > templates > customer > home.html` try with templates folder in same level of web_project

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70141544/django-template-exceptions-templatedoesnotexist-customer-base-html/70141561#comment123991854_70141582

Comment: No sir it is not working.      https://stackoverflow.com/users/17525592/nawaf-bhatti

Answer (score 0):

Check in your **settings.py** that this line you have configured or not
you have not created **customer** folder inside your **templates** folder or you forgot to add your **base.html** inside **customer** folder

```
TEMPLATES = [
   {
     ....
     'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
   }
]
```

Comment: 'TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR /  'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
'  My settings.py

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not exactly defined. But the problem is in the placement of your templates folder.

In `settings.py`:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR /  'templates'], # adding templates folder to base directory of each app
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            # ... some options here ...
        },
    },
]
```

If You have an app called Customer then inside the app there's the templates directory then in views:

```
def Hall(request):
    return render(request, "Hall.html", {"title":"Hall"})
```

should get the `Hall.html` placed in the templates folder of the same.

Comment: still not working

Comment: Template postmortem says                                                                                                     
                                      ' django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\Users\Nawaf Bhatti\Desktop\New\web_project\template\base.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Nawaf Bhatti\Desktop\New\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\base.html (Source does not exist)
'

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the folder structure like below:

```
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── customer
├── templates
│   └── customer
│       └── base.html
│       └── Hall.html
│       └── Food_item.html
│       └── About_us.html
└── Web_project
```

Comment: yes my folder structure is correct.